# Logical Operators and multiple Return values in Return-Statements of Typescript Functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a more general programming question that I was discussing with a collegue and I am curious what the community says about this;

Let´s take a Typescript Function like this one:

```
hasValue(param: string, checkValue: string): boolean {
        const value = this.url.searchParams.get(param);
        return value && value === checkValue;
}
```

I would expect that return value AND a Logical operation in a Function called somewhere else could evaluate first to true, but then to false, if the result of value === checkValue is not true; hence, the calling Function would first get true as a result and then false, which would break the program flow.

I would expect to handle this like this (in Pseudocode, as I am more familiar with Java):

```
if (value === checkValue)
{return value}

else {
break;
}
```

So that there is no condition when the Return-Statement could return first true, then false when calling the Function; In an asynchronious call, this could problems because further Callbacks, Functions could be executed when the Return-Statement is true and afterwards evaluates to false, from my point-of-view.

As the Function is returning two Values, I also think that this might break the program flow in case one or the other is false, when expected true and vice versa.

What does the Community think?

Comment: "*What does the Community think?*" about what exactly? You laid out how you *think* something works and, to be honest, I am not really sure I understand it. `return value && value === checkValue;` returns a single value, not two. You seem to say that it should return two things.

Comment: This is an equivalent return statement to yours `return (value && value === checkValue);`, does this help? I don't think I understood your issue.

Comment: @VLAZ: Ok, it returns a single value - so is this a good practice to return a value before assigning it? I would have expected the other way round, first assigning, then returning it

Comment: @DieWebagenten why would it be a problem? You mention async calls but *there is no multithreading happening*. So, you cannot have two calls that start to be evaluated simultaneously but end up with different results.

Comment: `return (value && value === checkValue);` behaves like `if (!!value) return value === checkValue); else return value;`. You probably don't want that - and honestly, [TypeScript should also be complaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcBqqA2ICmAFAA6oBOqAtgFyLpRkxgDmANIhMvhANbZ75a9RiwCUtAEZw4OfKiQBvAFCJVa1RAT1EAN1wFEAXkRh8Ad0QBVAEoAZQjjgRUsBADpkZfMFFv0csk4ABXIqdDdmfCgSUMpRAG4VdTUvKBAyJD0BRAAyHN19fCNDY05uPkLEgF8gA). You probably are looking for `return value != null && value === checkValue;`

Comment: @Bergi TBH, I think `return value === checkvalue` is enough. Assuming `strictNullChecks` is used. But I think OP used the code just to illustrate the point, rather than as a definite working code. I'm just not entirely sure what the point is.